# What would the prefered data type for single letter or number

Tags: database, vb.net, types

I am trying to create my first database based application that organizes technical drawings with their revision history.

For my class **'drawing'**, I don't know which data type to use for the revision numbers of the drawings.

The naming convention for drawing revisions works in a way that the drawing identifier starts with 0 (first drawing) and then goes up alphanumerical A, B, C, etc.

Sometimes our customers require a numerical naming convention (in the style of 0, 1, 2, 3, etc.)

Is it practical to just declare the variable as string or is there a simpler way to organize these values while still being able to sort the drawings in the correct sequence?

The reason why I ask, is that someone once told me that if working with databases requires some more thought than a regular application.

Comment: You can't use a numeric data type for data that is not numeric.  `varchar(2)` if you want all that data stored in one column, or else two columns for text and numbers and a third column to indicate which is being used.

Comment: You could use a string for the user input and use an internal value you can control and compare.

Comment: What happens after 9 or Z ?

Comment: @the_lotus 9 would become 10 and Z would become AA. But, as 10 might be a realistic AA is not likely to happen. This means the drawing would be 26 revisions old, and it would never happen. 10 is extreme also but it could occur.

Comment: If this is automatic, you could have a revision number (number in database) with a bit indicating the display type (numeric or letters). Then convert 2 to B in the UI. If this is a user input value, I would stick with a varchar (string). It's also hard to help without knowing all the business rule.